# Need a regular expression for inserting 2 string objects between which there must be a number other than zero

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I am a beginner level programmer in Objective-C.
The actual case is as under, when I am using NSPredicate class to extract string from a dictionary. 
Please help me to find the regular expression for inserting 2 string objects between which there must be a number other than zero.

Example:

```
prefixPattern = @"2.";
suffixPattern = @".0.0.0";
```

then finalPattern must be like `@"%@SingleDigitRequiredHereWhichIsNotZero%@",prefixPattern,suffixPattern`

searching results should be like 2.1.0.0.0 , 2.2.0.0.0 
but must not be like 2.0.0.0.0

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"header beginswith[c] %@",prefixPattern];
searchedHeader = [_jsonDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

//Filter 2
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"header endswith[c] %@",suffixPattern];
searchedHeader2 = [searchedHeader filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate2];

//Filter 3
NSPredicate *predicate3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"header matches '[%@][1-9][%@]'",prefixPattern,suffixPattern];
//In the above line I m trying to exclude zero. Here I want only a single digit which is not zero.
searchedHeader3 = [searchedHeader filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate3];
NSLog(@"%@",[searchedHeader3 description]);
```

Comment: Try `'[%@][^0]*[%@]'`.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev but it doesn't worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it compounds the pattern in a separate line

```
NSString *prefixPattern = @"2";
NSString *suffixPattern = @"0.0.0";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.[1-9].%@", prefixPattern, suffixPattern];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"header matches %@", pattern];
searchedHeader2 = [searchedHeader filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```